# My GIF is saving blank

Tags: animation, gif

so I've created an animated GIF using line drawing on a black background, and whenever I try to Save as/Export as/Save for web legacy, the animation does not appear, just the black background. Any idea why that's happening?[image: This is what it looks like when I'm trying to save. just a blank background]

[image: this is what its supposed to look like]

Comment: Can you add any more information to your post. Maybe some screenshots or the source file?

Comment: What software are you viewing your gif with?

Comment: im using photoshop CC

Comment: Are all the frames black? What happens if you press play?

Comment: yup all the frames are black if I press play it moves through the frames but it's still blank

Comment: Do you realise your GIF is set to 3508 x 2480px. Seriously?!  The GIF format was designed for small web graphics. Also the zoom is at 100% - so you are only seeing a tiny black part of the whole.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is just because you have a large document and the zoom level is 100%.

You are only seeing the upper left corner of the image.

Double click the hand tool to fit to view.

Comment: Thank you!! :) But it still saves as a blank background even after I fit to view

Comment: Thank you!! :) But it still saves as a blank background even after I fit to view

Comment: Are you sure? Where do you preview it? Maybe there is the same problem there. Btw, your gif is 3508 x 2480px which is way bigger than normal. You should scale it so it is more fit for wherever you are going to display it.